# Doubts with differential geometry notation in Frankel

Tags: differential-geometry, notation

This is from Frankel's *The Geometry of Physics*:

> **Problem 2.3(2)** Consider the tangent bundle to a manifold $M$.
>
> 1. Show that under a change of coordinates in $M$, $\partial/\partial q$ depends on both $\partial/\partial q'$ and $\partial/\partial \dot{q}'$.

I'm not entirely sure what $\partial/\partial \dot{q}$ means. If $q = (q^1, \dots, q^n)$ is a set of coordinates for $M$, then $\partial/\partial q^i$ are the basis vectors for the tangent space of $M$ at a given point. The tangent bundle to $M$, $TM$, is a $2n$-dimensional manifold, and so to label a point in $TM$ we need a $2n$-tuple of numbers $(q^1, \dots , q^n, \dot{q}^1, \dots , \dot{q}^n)$. I guess that then $\{\partial/ \partial q^i, \partial/ \partial \dot{q}^i\}$ would be a basis for the tangent space to $TM$.

Is this the correct interpretation? If so, does this imply that the tangent space to $TM$ can be written as the direct sum of two subspaces, the tangent space to $M$ and the tangent space to the tangent space to $M$? Or is this a coordinate dependent identification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your interpretation is correct - given a set of coordinates $q$ on $M$, a tangent vector in the domain of these coordinates can be completely described by its base point $q$ and its component in each of the $\partial/\partial q^i$ directions; so calling the component of the vector in the $\partial/\partial q^i$ direction $\dot q^i$ we have a coordinate system $(q,\dot q)$ for $TM$.

The direct sum decomposition you're talking about indeed depends on coordinates - the "horizontal directions" (i.e. the vectors in $T_p TM$ we would like to identify with $T_p M$) are those in which the components of vectors remain constant while their base points change - this dependence on components is a dependence on the coordinate system. Thus there is no canonical horizontal subspace without some extra structure, which is known as a connection.

The vertical subspace $V_p$ (directions in which the base point is fixed), however, is coordinate independent; thus you can write down a decomposition of the form $T_p TM = V_p \oplus (T_p TM / V_p)$. A connection is then exactly the extra information that identifies the quotient $T_p TM / V_p$ with a subspace of $T_p TM$.

Comment: hi Anthony sorry to revamp such a long discussion. I cannot understand how $\frac{\partial}{\partial q}$ can depend on $\frac{\partial}{\partial \dot{q}^{'}}$.While I can understand that $\frac{\partial}{\partial \dot{q}}$ can depend on $\frac{\partial}{\partial{q}^{'}}$, I can't find an example for the case mentioned by Frenkel, as the transition function does not depend on the velocities, whereas of course the Jacobian can depend on the positions. Would you have such example? thanks

Comment: @l4teLearner: if you write out the chain rule for $\partial/\partial q^i$ in terms of coordinates $q', \dot q'$, you should see that the fact $\dot q'$ can depend on $q$ implies that $\partial/\partial q^i$ can depend on $\partial/\partial \dot q'.$ If you need more help with this I recommend opening a new question, since this one is really just about the interpretation of $\dot q$.

Comment: hi Anthony thanks to your hints I could proceed with the exercise. I still have some doubts that I reported here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4782215/frankel-exercise-on-coordinate-invariant-vector-fields-on-tm cheers