# Frankel exercise on coordinate invariant vector fields on $TM$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, classical-mechanics, tangent-bundle

I am doing the following exercise from Frankel's *The geometry of physics* and I am having some doubts:

> **2.3(2)** Consider the tangent bundle to a manifold $M$.
>
> (i) Show that under a change of coordinates in $M$, $\partial/\partial q$
> depends on both $\partial/\partial q'$ and $\partial/{\partial \dot q'}$.
>
> (ii) Is the locally defined vector field $\sum_j\dot q^j \partial/\partial q^j$ well defined on all of $TM$?
>
> (iii) Is $\sum_j\dot q^j \partial/\partial \dot q^j$ well defined?
>
> (iv) If any
> of the above in (ii),(iii) is well defined, can you produce an intrinsic definition?

For (i) first of all, I will assume, as in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/620798/doubts-with-differential-geometry-notation-in-frankel), that by $\frac{\partial}{\partial \dot q'}$ we mean a *tangent vector* of a point of $TM$, the tangent bundle of $M$.

If we indicate the transition functions for a coordinate patch of $M$ as $q^i=q^i(q'^1,...,q'^n)$ where $n$ is the dimension of $M$, the coordinates for the corresponding patch of the tangent space $TM$ are $$q^1,...,q^n, \dot q^1,...,\dot q^n $$ where $q^i=q^i(q'^1,...,q'^n)$ and $\dot q^i=\frac{\partial q^i}{\partial q'^j}\dot q'^j$.

To see how the vector $\frac{\partial}{\partial q}$ is represented in the "$q'$" system, I worked as follows: I took a function *on TM* and differentiated it by $\frac{\partial}{\partial q}$. Then I applied the chain rule (Einstein's notation is used below):

$$\frac{\partial f(q'^1,...,q'^n,\dot q'^1,...,\dot q'^n) }{\partial q^i}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial q'^j} \frac{\partial q'^j}{\partial q^i}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial \dot q'^j} \frac{\partial \dot q'^j}{\partial q^i}$$
so
$$\frac{\partial }{\partial q^i}=\frac{\partial q'^j}{\partial q^i}\frac{\partial }{\partial q'^j} +\frac{\partial \dot q'^j}{\partial q^i}\frac{\partial }{\partial \dot q'^j}$$

then I further expanded $\frac{\partial \dot q'^j}{\partial q^i}$
as $\frac{\partial}{\partial q^i}(\frac{\partial q'^j}{\partial q^k}\dot q^k)=\frac{\partial}{\partial q^i}(\frac{\partial q'^j}{\partial q^k})\dot q^k+\frac{\partial q'^j}{\partial q^k}\frac{\partial}{\partial q^i}(\dot q^k)$ getting, as $q^k$ and $\dot q^k$ are two independent variables, $$\frac{\partial }{\partial q^i}=\frac{\partial q'^j}{\partial q^i}\frac{\partial }{\partial q'^j} +\{\frac{\partial}{\partial q^i}(\frac{\partial q'^j}{\partial q^k})\dot q^k\}\frac{\partial }{\partial \dot q'^j}$$
Equivalently, I got the same result considering a curve $c(t)$ with values in $TM$ and calculating the "differential" of the transition function (of the full coordinates of $TM$), then applying such differential to the vector $\frac{\partial}{\partial q^k}$.

*I wonder if this result is correct and if it was required by the exercise to further expand* $\frac{\partial \dot q'^j}{\partial q^i}$ *as I didn't know anything a priori about this expression.*

*As for (ii) and (iii) I believe that "well defined" means "invariant in form to coordinate transformation"?*

Let's start from (iii). I wanted to evaluate how $\sum_j\dot q^j \partial/\partial \dot q^j$ is represented in $q'$ system so I applied the same logic as in (i) getting

$$\frac{\partial f(q'^1,...,q'^n,\dot q'^1,...,\dot q'^n) }{\partial \dot q^i}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial q'^j} \frac{\partial q'^j}{\partial \dot q^i}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial \dot q'^j} \frac{\partial \dot q'^j}{\partial \dot q^i}$$

I think that the first term of the sum is zero, because if I take a curve in $TM$ which stays on the same fibre of a point $p \in M$, the $M$ coordinates will stay constant for any coordinate patch. A curve with velocity $\partial / \partial \dot q$ is such a curve, so we have that $\frac{\partial q'^j}{\partial \dot q^i}=0$.
Then, as we know that $\dot q^j=\sum_i \frac{\partial q^j}{\partial q'^i}\dot q'^i$, as this is a linear relationship, all the $\dot q^i$ are independent and, again, the $\frac{\partial q^j}{\partial \dot q'^i}=0$, we can write that $\frac{\partial \dot q'^j}{\partial \dot q^i}=\frac{\partial q'^j}{\partial  q^i}$. Summing all together we get

$$ \sum_j\dot q^j \partial/\partial \dot q^j = \sum_j\{(\sum_k \frac{\partial q^j}{\partial q'^k}\dot q'^k)(\sum_i \frac{\partial q'^i}{\partial  q^j}\frac{\partial }{\partial \dot q'^i})\}= \sum_k \sum_i \{ \sum_j( \frac{\partial q^j}{\partial q'^k}\dot q'^k)(\frac{\partial q'^i}{\partial  q^j}\frac{\partial }{\partial \dot q'^i})\}= \sum_k\dot q^k \partial/\partial \dot q^k$$
as in the last term I have the product of the Jacobian by its inverse.

*On the other hand, for (ii) I write* $\sum_j\dot q^j\frac{\partial}{\partial q^j}$ *in the $q'$ coordinates using the result in (i). Is it enough to note that the terms in* $\partial/\partial \dot q'^j$ *do not vanish, to prove that *$\sum_j\dot q^j\frac{\partial}{\partial q^j}$* is not invariant in form? As I don't see this time how this could simplify.*

*Last part of the exercise is (iv), which I assume should be to find a coordinate independent version for* $\sum_j\dot q^j \partial/\partial \dot q^j$. *I feel this should be a similar procedure to the definition of the Poincare' 1-form, but I cannot formalize anything useful. Any hint?*

thanks

Comment: Here's one natural vector field on $TM$: for every $(x,v) \in TM$, consider the curve $t\mapsto (x, {\rm e}^tv)$. Its value at $t=0$ is $(x,v)$, and so the velocity at $t=0$ is an element ot $T_{(x,v)}(TM)$. So, $X_{(x,v)} = \frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t}\big|_{t=0} (x,{\rm e}^tv) $ does define a vector field on $TM$. It is often called the "Euler vector field" for hopefully obvious reasons. Why don't you go ahead and express this is coordinates to see what happens? :)

Comment: thanks @IvoTerek indeed it was much simpler than I thought. just a matter of solving one of the simplest differential equations. indeed, in any coordinate system the Euler vector field has the same form. if by any chance you could have a look at the rest of my calculations/questions it would be much appreciated. cheers!